# PhoneGap app scrolling over an iframe

Tags: jquery, cordova, iframe, scroll, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap app (with jquery mobile) in which i load some content in iframes. The iframes in themselves do not have scrollbars and aren't scrollable (the content of iframe is a div with an image)

**The problem:**

When scrolling up or down the page scrolls perfectly *except* when the gesture is made on the iframes, then the page stays still. I want the parent page to scroll normally even when the gestures are made on the iframes, as though iframe were an image or a div.

**What i have tried:**
putting

```
pointer-events:none;
```

in the body of the iframe src.

It doesn't do anything. Clicks are disabled but if you attempt to scroll on the iframe nothing gets scrolled.

Any ideas how it can be done?
I am testing the app on an android device.

Comment: can u put iframe inside a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe's seamless attribute is the simple answer here.

```
<iframe src="" seamless>
```

That ought do it.